# Covering space in B. O'Neill book, semi-riemannian geom.

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, geometric-topology

i'm reading the Appendix A in B. O'Neill's book semi-riemannian geometry and he says this.
[image]

I'm thinking on $\text{exp}:\mathbb{R}\to S^1$ dose not provide an izo at the level of fundamental groups. What is wrong here?

Comment: one-to-one means injective not isomorphism

Comment: oh, now make sens!